# Perform validation of role hierarchy before saving in database in nest

Tags: nestjs

I have a table of role which contains role name and its priority..

```
id  role_name    priority
1   SuperAdmin     1
2   User           2


... so on
```

The condition is that whenever user does any create or update operation on any entity it has to follow the hierarchy like SuperAdmin can create User but User cannot create SuperAdmin

I have created a function checkHierarchy and import it to different modules wherever required and explicitly checked it like this

commonfile.ts

```
function checkHierarchy(rolePriority1, rolePriority2) { 
  return true // if can create 
  return false // cannot create
}
```

Another file user.ts

```
import checkHierarchy from common


function createUser() {
 const status = checkHierarchy(rp1 , rp2)
 if(!status) throw err(Dont have permission to create)
 userRepository.create(user)
}
```

I want to know is there any technique in nest js so that i can perform operation like this

```
this.checkHierarchy().userRepository.create(User)

#if checkHierarchy method return false then entire operation fails.
```

Comment: I think this can be achieved using Middlewares. If you are using mongoose, check out hooks/Middlewares. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html If TypeORM, then check out listeners & subscribers. https://typeorm.io/#/listeners-and-subscribers

Comment: Thanks, I wanted exactly the same thing